# JDBC dialect when writing Spark to Hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a dataframe from Spark 2.2.0 to Hive 2.1 through a JDBC connection. **I know this is not the recommended way** and that a direct connection using hive-site.xml should be configured but that is not an option for me currently due to factors outside of my control...so I'm stuck with JDBC at the moment.

I can read from Hive using JDBC but have to override the JDBC dialect quoteIdentifier method and specify the fetchsize to actually see any output from the dataframe in Spark.

Although inconvenient, this is okay with me for now. However, I am having trouble writing back to Hive now. I think I need to make additional changes to the JDBC dialect to write back as I'm getting this error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while 
compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 cannot recognize input 
near '.' 'name' 'TEXT' in column type
```

This is my process for reading via JDBC:

1.) Created db-properties.flat file with my username, pass, url, and driver.

```
url=jdbc:hive2://xxxx.com:10000/default
driver=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
user=xxxxxx
password=xxxxxx
```

2.) Open Spark Shell and run the below code to read table:

```
import java.io.Fileimport java.util.Properties
import java.io.FileInputStream
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialects, JdbcType, JdbcDialect}

val conf = new SparkConf()
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val dbProperties = new Properties

dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/xxxxxx/db-properties.flat")))
val url = dbProperties.getProperty("url")
val jdbcDriver = dbProperties.getProperty("driver")
val jdbcFetchsize = dbProperties.setProperty("fetchsize","10")

/* Update JDBC dialect */
val HiveDialect = new JdbcDialect { 
override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:hive2") || url.contains("hive2")
override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String ={ s"$colName" }
}

JdbcDialects.registerDialect(HiveDialect)


val myTable  = "xxxxxx"
val df = spark.read.jdbc(url,myTable,dbProperties)

df.show()
```

3.) I am able to read the data without issues in step 2, but I cannot write to Hive from Spark using JDBC. Below is the code:

```
df.write.mode("error").jdbc(url,"newtable",dbProperties)
```

...which results in this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while 
compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 cannot recognize input 
near '.' 'name' 'TEXT' in column type
```

Does anyone have recommendations as to how I can modify the dialect to write back to Hive from Spark JDBC or any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought about the IMPALA JDBC Driver. Also, circumstances outside of my control - all very interesting. I am not sure ypu can use JDBC on a write to the HDFS domain / Hive like this. But may be you can. When you save to parquet you don't provide a JDBC connection. But let us what the experts say.

Comment: You may be right about not being able to write to Hive via JDBC. I think it is technically possible but from what I am seeing, there is an issue with the quoteIdentifier when writing back to Hive as well. May need to find a way to add a back tick around column names, because without it the create table command isn't parsing correctly.
Getting the below error now:
    org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling 
    statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 cannot recognize input near 
    '"mytable.col1"' 'VARCHAR' '('in column name or primary key or foreign key

Comment: I have never seen it. Take the path of least resistance. What does happen is that the tools use the IMPALA JDBC Connection for Hive data. Need to note about saving as Hive compatible tables via SPARK. A little confusing some of the documentation on older releases.